# No session found for current thread. Works in local QA, fails in production

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I know there are tons of questions related to this issue in SO. However my problem is different, my code works fine in local and QA, but giving this error in production.

```
NFO   | jvm 1    | main    org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for    
  current thread
INFO   | jvm 1    | main       at    
  org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)

 INFO   | jvm 1    | main        at 
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
```

I can provide further details if needed, however I don't think you guys want to look at the code, when code is working in local and QA. Please help if anyone has encountered this situation.

**EDIT1:**

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 | [1;31mFATAL [HTTP41] ] [Http500Handler] An Exception has occured in the application
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 | org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.ppc.myapp.integration.dao.contract.impl.contractDAOImpl.getAccountStatus(contractDAOImpl.java:36)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getAccountStatus(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.mycompany.integration.customer.impl.CustomerCreditServiceImpl.isCreditWorthy(CustomerCreditServiceImpl.java:117)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.mycompany.integration.eligibility.impl.EligibilityLookupServiceImpl.checkMaxOrderMinCreditWorthiness(EligibilityLookupServiceImpl.java:230)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.checkMaxOrderMinCreditWorthiness(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.mycompany.facades.order.impl.PPACheckoutFacadeImpl.getMaxOrderMinSalaryCreditWorthyCheck(PPACheckoutFacadeImpl.java:534)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at com.mycompany.storefront.controllers.pages.checkout.CheckoutController.checkout(CheckoutController.java:94)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.065 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(PlatformFilterChain.java:203)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at com.mycompany.storefront.filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilterInternal(NoCacheFilter.java:36)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(PlatformFilterChain.java:175)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at com.mycompany.storefront.filters.client.PPAOpenEnrollmentFilter.doFilterInternal(PPAOpenEnrollmentFilter.java:82)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(PlatformFilterChain.java:175)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at com.mycompany.storefront.filters.client.PPAClientFilter.doFilterInternal(PPAClientFilter.java:52)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.066 |     at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.PlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(PlatformFilterChain.java:175)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at com.mycompany.storefront.filters.btg.BTGSegmentFilter.doFilterInternal(BTGSegmentFilter.java:47)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor969.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:35:48.067 |     at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:686)
```

Comment: What does it mean that it works in "local and QA"? Unit tests or user testing? And does the word "main" in the log indicate a thread name? Can you share full stack trace (and by "full" I mean full... want to make sure you have servlet and TX AOP on the stack).

Comment: I have edited the post with stacktrace. sorry for wrong formatting. It has passed all QA, and User testing, without showing this issue.

Comment: Don't be sorry for the formatting, fix it up if you want someone to help you.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are getting this exception?

Comment: @Pradeep,no point in posting code, code works in local and QA environments.

Comment: If it works in QA and not PROD, then it means something IS different. Do you have the same jar libraries versions? (Spring, Hibernate, everything) Are you deploying to the same app server (type and version)? Are you using the same JDK? Are these deployments on the same OS? etc

Comment: Can not see anything suspicious in the stack trace... can you verify that you don't have Spring JARs on shared class loader path? I can also see that you are mixing CGLIB and JDK proxying... but I don't think that matters.

Comment: We found the issue. The context initialization failed during server start due to a missing property(from property file) in one of the bean injections.Application was up and most of the things were working but failed in this case. We had to back out build to Prod because of the issue. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create above findings as an answer to this question? want to make sure that I follow the SO rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue. The context initialization failed during server start due to a missing property(from property file) in one of the bean injections.Application was up and most of the things were working but failed in this case.

We had to back out the build to Production because of the issue.

Thanks to all for your help.

EDIT:2

Adding the stacktrace seen in the server startup, we overlooked server startup logs, as We found the application up and running fine.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:37:25.977 | [m[0;31mERROR [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [Registry] Error while initialization global application context
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:37:25.977 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'importPaymentInfoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'migration.paymentinfo.dir'
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:37:25.977 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:37:25.977 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:37:25.977 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/05/13 07:37:25.977 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
```

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved the issue. However can you describe whether there was another exception in the log to which you didn't pay attention? Or how is it possible that "context init failed", but still judging on the stack trace, everything was up and running. Thank you... btw. it is not necessary, I am just curious :).

Comment: Added the error stacktrace from server startup logs.